# Visual Studio Doesn't List WSL as Platform Toolset

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, msbuild, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm following [this tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-with-visual-studio-2019-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/). Everything seems to be fine (linux subsystem is setup fine, I think), but WSL is not showing up as a platform toolset for compilation for C/C++ projects.
[image]

Using visual studio 16.9.5

Comment: Do you have follow this document to enable subsystem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: @DylanZhu-MSFT Yes, I did. I can connect to the WSL if I start the ssh service, so I know it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can check these steps, which can make me find windows subsystem for linux in visual studio:

**Enable subsystem:**

1. Enable windows subsystem for windows

   - Run powershell as administrator
   - Run this command: `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart`
2. Restart machine
3. download and install linux app

**Configure linux environment:**

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt install g++ gdb make rsync zip`
3. `sudo apt-get install openssh-client`
4. `sudo apt-get install nano`
5. `sudo service ssh restart`

**Configure visual studio:**

1. Add connection in Tools/Options/Cross Manager
2. The windows subsystem will auto display in platform toolset
   [image]

Comment: As I said in my comment, that works, but I'd like the direct integration. Is there anyway around it?

Comment: @lajoh90686 , the subsystem should be auto added into toolset. Not sure what you missed, I have updated my answer and post the whole steps which can work on my side.

Comment: Reran all those commands & same thing; still doesn't show up. All those things were already installed, it looks.

Comment: Do you have a try to repair or re-install visual studio?

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled the C++ for Linux portion, but not the whole thing.

Comment: Was anyone able to find the solution to this? I am having the exact same problem. I followed all the above steps including repair VS and reinstalling C++ Linux component, but I still don't see the WSL options in Toolset.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the platform in your project properties to match your WSL installation. In your screenshot "All Platforms" are selected, but your WSL installation can't target ARM, ARM64, x86 and x64 at the same time. You have to change it to (most likely) x86 or x64, then "GCC for Windows Subystem for Linux" (or in my case "WSL2 GCC Toolset") will apear in the drop down.